# SQL Join, Selecting Earliest instance and Preserving Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables containing the following data:

```
(File)
    +----+------+...
    | Id | File |
    +----+------+...
    |  1 | Fizz |
    |  2 | Buzz |
    +----+------+...

(Work)    
    +----+------+-----------+-----------+...
    | Id | File |   Step    |   Date    |
    +----+------+-----------+-----------+...
    |  1 | Fizz | Created   | 1/1/2015  |
    |  2 | Fizz | StartWork | 1/2/2015  |
    |  3 | Fizz | WorkDone  | 1/3/2015  |
    |  4 | Buzz | StartWork | 2/16/2015 |
    |  5 | Buzz | WorkDone  | 2/17/2015 |
    |  6 | Buzz | WorkDone  | 2/18/2015 |
    |  7 | Buzz | Closed    | 2/19/2015 |
    +----+------+-----------+-----------+...
```

I would like to generate the following result:

```
(Query Result)
    +------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
    | File |  Created  | StartWork | WorkDone  |  Closed   |
    +------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
    | Fizz | 1/1/2015  | 1/2/2015  | 1/3/2015  | NULL      |
    | Buzz | NULL      | 2/16/2015 | 2/17/2015 | 2/19/2015 |
    +------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The query should return a single row for any File, with the earliest instance of a given Step for that File from the Work table. For example, 'WorkDone' occurs on two dates for the Buzz file, but I would like the Joined table to select only the WorkDone on 2/17/2015, which is the earliest time WorkDone occurred.

Also, for Steps which do not exist for a given File, I would like to show NULL.

Here is the query that I have been working on, but I'm afraid that I'm on the wrong track. I am not capturing NULL entries, and I believe I am using MIN incorrectly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
f.File, 
MIN(workCreated.Date) AS 'Created', 
MIN(workStart.Date) AS 'StartWork', 
MIN(workDone.Date) AS 'WorkDone',
MIN(workClosed.Date) AS 'Closed'
FROM File f
LEFT JOIN Work workCreated ON f.File = workCreated.File
LEFT JOIN Work workStart ON f.File = workStart.File
LEFT JOIN Work workDone ON f.File = workDone.File
LEFT JOIN Work workClosed ON f.File = workClosed.File
WHERE
workCreated.Step = 'Created' AND
workStart.Step = 'StartWork' AND
workDone.Step = 'WorkDone' AND
workClosed.Step = 'Closed'
GROUP BY f.File
```

Comment: Sorry about the poorly worded title to the question. I am not actually "Preserving Nulls", but inserting a NULL entry into the table when a Step does not exist for a given File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to ignore the IDs for joining, instead use File and Step. Then you can aggregate on the minimum Date. Case logic can be used, but that becomes a bit more complex. Strictly speaking you don't need to use the File table.

```
select f.File,
Created=min(c.Date),
StartWork=min(s.Date),
WorkDone=min(d.Date),
Closed=min(l.Date)
from File as f
left join Work as c on f.File=c.File and c.Step='Created'
left join Work as s on f.File=s.File and s.Step='StartWork'
left join Work as d on f.File=d.File and d.Step='WorkDone'
left join Work as l on f.File=l.File and l.Step='Closed'
group by f.File
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great, upon an initial try with this structure, the query seems to return what I'm looking for.

Comment: Interestingly, both this method and Gordon's below (albeit modified to use min instead of max) return similar sets. Your query also includes records for which no records at all exist in Work table for a given File from the File table, which is preferable in my case. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: To anyone reading this answer, it is overly complicated for what the OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, how would you do it simpler yet have min date value and null values (for missing dates) as the OP wanted? Your solution below ignores null values completely. I'm always looking for simpler solutions.

Comment: @EmacsUser . . . Conditional aggregation does not ignore `NULL` values.  If nothing matches, it will return `NULL`.  Admittedly, it only returns files that are in the `work` table.  That is true in the data the OP shows; extra files are easily included with one extra `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that's what I thought -- perils of premature optimization. You make a point at the expense of incompleteness.  We can consider join optimizations later based on the relative sizes of the two tables, coverage indexes, and other factors unspecified at this time. For example four joins may be faster than aggregating the entire work table for some sizes. However, null values were specified, two tables were, min values for dates were, and I'd rather anyone reading this get the complete answer to the question as asked instead of an incomplete attempt at an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select w.file,
       min(case when step = 'Created' then date end) as Created,
       min(case when step = 'StartWork' then date end) as StartWork,
       min(case when step = 'WorkDone' then date end) as WorkDone,
       min(case when step = 'Closed' then date end) as Closed
from Work w
group by w.file;
```

The structure of your data suggests that `file` should probably not be in the `Work` table.  The `id` should be.  Then you can join to the other table.

Comment: How does max ensure "earliest time" as per OP's question?

Comment: Thanks - this seems to return what I am looking for if I change MAX here to MIN. Emacs User's answer above returns a similar set, however it is returning a greater number of rows. I will need to determine what the discrepancy is here. Thanks again.

Comment: @WesDoyle . . . You have multiple duplicate values, which is why you are getting results.  For anyone reading the question, I would dissuade you from doing four joins with an aggregation, when a single aggregation is sufficient.